# In WPF, how to draw a composite geometry with Path Markup Syntax?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to draw a figure with [Path Markup Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/path-markup-syntax) as below:

[image]

And I tried this in xaml:

```
<Path Margin="20" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="Black" Data="M0,0L15,10L0,20ZM5,0L20,10L5,20"></Path>
```

And I got this:

[image]

**So, what's the right syntax?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw two single lines instead of a polyline figure:

```
<Path Margin="20" Fill="Black" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1"
      StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round"
      Data="M0,0 L15,10 0,20Z M5,0 L20,10 M5,20 L20,10"/>
```